# MySQL : Insert Statement to add a record in TABLE_1

Tags: mysql, sql

A single insert statement to add a new record in TABLE_1 for which :

1. TABLE_1_ID value to be inserted as total count of records in TABLE_1 + 1.
2. COLUMN_NAME will have value as "ABC".
3. TABLE_2_ID value should be picked from TABLE_2 based on value of
   COLUMN_NAME which is "ABC".
4. TABLE_3_ID value should be picked from TABLE_3 based on value of
   COLUMN_NAME which is "ABC".

All above specified statements has to be done using Single Insert Statement. Schemas of all 3 tables are below :

### TABLE_1

```
COLUMN_NAME     COLUMN_TYPE     IS_NULLABLE     COLUMN_KEY     COLUMN_DEFAULT    
-----------    --------------  --------------  -------------   --------------                   
TABLE_1_ID      smallint(6)     NO              PRI            (null)                      
COLUMN_NAME     varchar(200)    YES                            (null)                      
TABLE_2_ID      smallint(6)     YES             MUL            (null)                      
TABLE_3_ID      smallint(6)     YES             MUL            (null)
```

### TABLE_2

```
COLUMN_NAME     COLUMN_TYPE     IS_NULLABLE     COLUMN_KEY     COLUMN_DEFAULT         
--------------  --------------  --------------  -------------  -----------------   
TABLE_2_ID      smallint(6)     NO              PRI            (null)                      
COLUMN_NAME     varchar(20)     YES                            (null)
```

### TABLE_3

```
COLUMN_NAME     COLUMN_TYPE     IS_NULLABLE     COLUMN_KEY     COLUMN_DEFAULT         
--------------  --------------  --------------  -------------  -----------------   
TABLE_3_ID      smallint(6)     NO              PRI            (null)                      
COLUMN_NAME     varchar(20)     YES                            (null)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1(TABLE_1_ID, COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_2_ID, TABLE_3_ID)
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1, 'ABC', (SELECT TABLE_2_ID FROM TABLE_2 WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'ABC'), (SELECT TABLE_3_ID FROM TABLE_3 WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'ABC') FROM TABLE_1
```

Comment: Please try and explain your answer, and why this is arguably the best solution.

Comment: I think that this is not the best solution, but it is a solution that meets the conditions that were raised in the question.
This solution is not ideal, for at least two reasons:
1. TABLE_1_ID may coincide with TABLE_1_ID that is already in the TABLE_1. A more correct solution would be to find the maximum identifier MAX(TABLE_1_ID) + 1.
2. In TABLE_2 and TABLE_3 there may be several entries with the name "ABC". Therefore, it is better to limit the subqueries to the output of a single record LIMIT 1.

Comment: Thanks for extending your answer! You can also directly include your points into your answer via an edit, so it is more visible. Thanks again for your contributions on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thanks Eugene & dennlinger for writing above comments, this adds more clearity to your answer.